# How to stop recorder of react-mic when parent component is suddenly unmounted and coulldn't update state in time?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-mic, which start/stops recording when a prop of start/stops is passed to it. It's working fine, but in some cases, when a user click on some other link in app while recorder is ON, the parent component of react-mic is unmounted suddenly and I'm not able to update this.state.record on time and since prop is not passed to react-mic, the recording dot is still ON in tab, so can someone suggest me how can i stop the recording or remove the red dot from tab?

```
import { ReactMic } from 'react-mic';

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

    stopRecording() {

        this.setState({
          record: false,
        });
    }

    render() {

        <ReactMic
            record={this.state.record} // defaults -> false.  Set to 
                                       // true to begin recording
            onStop={this.onStop}       // callback to execute when 
                                       // audio stops recording
            onData={this.onData}
         />
    }
}
```

Not able to update this.state.record, since ParentComponent is unmounted suddenly

Answer (score 1):

Do it in `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method:

```
import { ReactMic } from 'react-mic';

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

    stopRecording = () => {

        this.setState({
          record: false,
        });
    }

    compoentWillUnmount(){
      this.stopRecording()
    }

    render() {

        <ReactMic
            record={this.state.record} // defaults -> false.  Set to 
                                       // true to begin recording
            onStop={this.onStop}       // callback to execute when 
                                       // audio stops recording
            onData={this.onData}
         />
    }
}
```

I've turned your function in arrow function because this is not clear if you have bound method in constructor